# How to show pointer head on vg-scrub-bar of video gular library?

Tags: cordova, ionic2, videogular

Here there is a simple line seek bar with no drag feature,

```
                        <vg-scrub-bar>
                            <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
                        </vg-scrub-bar>-->

                        <vg-controls *ngIf="showControlls" 
                            </vg-controls>

                            <video webkit-playsinline playsinline [vgMedia]="media" poster="assets/blank.png" #media id="singleVideo" preload="auto"
                            crossorigin (click)="togglePlay();" [src]="src">


    </video>
</vg-player>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update Your Code to use vgSlider attribute on `<vg-scrub-bar-current-time>`

```
<vg-scrub-bar>
  <vg-scrub-bar-current-time [vgSlider]="true"></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
</vg-scrub-bar>
```